# How can I convert $S=\{\{p_1,p_2\},\{q_1,q_2\}\}$ to $S=\{p_1p_2,q_1q_2\}$

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

This is a simple example I need to convert this form $S=\{\{p_1,p_2\},\{q_1,q_2\}\}$  into this form  $S=\{p_1p_2,q_1q_2\}$

```
s = {{Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}, {Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[
   q, 2]}}
```

Thanks

Comment: All you need is: `Times@@@s`

Comment: @wxffles ... and love!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mathematical process with the process of adding (plus) to the multiplication process (Times)

$$\{1, 1\}.\{\{p_1, p_2\}, \{q_1, q_2\}\}=\{p_1+q_1, p_2+q_2\}$$

So

```
s = {{Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}, {Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[
        q, 2]}};
    Sort[s.Array[1 &, 2] /. Plus -> Times]
```

[image]

Comment: How unconventional!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This is a mathematical process with the process of adding (plus) to the multiplication process(Times)

Comment: This doesn't work for numerical values! Also why the `Sort`? Consider `s={{a, d}, {c, b}}`.

Comment: @M.Stern Is just an idea for this question

Comment: Your replacement of `Plus[]` with `Times[]` will of course fail if the entries are numeric. If you really want to use this approach, use `Inner[]` instead: `Inner[Times, s, {1, 1}, Times]`.

Comment: (+1) Or maybe `s// #[[All, 1]].DiagonalMatrix[#[[All, 2]]] &`